# How to get information from sshd about established remote tunnels

Tags: ssh-tunneling, openssh, tunneling

I have a server running on which from many different places people log on via ssh and open remote ssh-tunnels to other places behind different firewalls.
Now I want to try to get an overview, which LISTEN-port connects to which connected ssh-session with an opened remote tunnel.
I have no access to the client ssh-computers.

e.g. the LISTEN-ports on the server

```
$ lsof -i4 -sTCP:LISTEN
sshd     5543   usera    9u  IPv4 97603715      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
sshd     5543   userb   11u  IPv4 97603719      0t0  TCP *:3060 (LISTEN)
sshd     5543   userc   13u  IPv4 97603723      0t0  TCP *:8889 (LISTEN)
```

How can I find out, which LISTEN port connects to the established  ssh-connections given by:

```
$ lsof -i TCP:22 -a -u root
sshd     5546 root    3u  IPv4 97603798      0t0  TCP server:ssh->client1:42896 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    11846 root    3u  IPv4 97193507      0t0  TCP server:ssh->client2:51586 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    11847 root    3u  IPv4 97193512      0t0  TCP server:ssh->client3:51588 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I know that they are related, but I can not make the mapping of ssh-connection (lower output) to LISTEN ports.
The sshd-process knows this but how can I get this information from him?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!